# Min / Max: how does key sort?

Tags: python, key, max, min

I am a bit puzzled by the behavior of the key argument in min() and max()

Let's say I have the following list: `c=[10,11,15,25,50]`

I want the max value above 20, so I do: `max(c,key= lambda x: x>20)`. Result is 25, should be 50.

I want the max value below 20, so I do:  `max(c,key= lambda x: x<20)`. Result is 10, should be 15.

Same thing with min(). If I want the min values above 20 (`min(c,key= lambda x: x>20)`), this will give me 10, instead of 25.

Can someone please help explain? I would like to understand better in order to avoid mistakes when dealing with different conditions.

Comment: A key of `lambda x: x>20` is just going to return `True` if `x>20`, `False` otherwise. It's not going to return the value of `x` itself.

Comment: What makes you think ``key= lambda x: x>20`` would *restrict* the output to values larger than 20? What "restriction" do you assume is applied by ``max(c,key= lambda x: -x)``?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not the correct way to use `max` instead you'd want to use a generator expression to filter out elements, then take the `max` of that

```
>>> max(i for i in c if i > 20)
50
```

If you pass that condition to `key` then the return value of that `lambda` will be used for sorting, and all of the values will simply be `True` or `False` (where `False < True`) so you'll get the first of the falsey values, in this case `10`.

The `key` argument is really intended to be used if you want to specify a way to access a particular piece of data for each item in your list. For example say I have this class

```
class point:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

If I want to find the largest point based on its `.y` value, that is a good time to use the `key` argument

```
>>> data = [point(1,2,3), point(3,2,1), point(9,8,7)]
>>> p = max(data, key = lambda pt: pt.y)
>>> p.y
8
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Cory.
I was actually using a piece of code for dates I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60109868/find-closest-past-date-in-list-of-dates
It was unclear to me how that worked so was playing with simple example.